# what is the work around to get All Pages in One request from TMDB?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, frontend, es6-promise

- I'm new in React js , I'm using TMDB service in my **REACT JS** project to get the Movies
  of a specific year (selected by the user )
- The request only returns the first page which contain 20 results  the
  only way to get all pages is to send the param &page=x in the request
  where x = the page number
- the basic and the trivial solution is : to get total_pages and then
  loop over them and add movies of each page to movies list , but it
  takes more time to be viewed in the view
- what is the solution or work around to get all results in one request
- below is samples of my code :
- getcurrentYearMovies() // gets only one page results,, getpageMoviess()
  // loop one pages and add each page result to all movies

[image]

Comment: if you are getting movies of the year, you technically only need to run the query once a year and store the results in a database to access the results for future calls. This will make the entire process run more efficiently.

Comment: but one of the project features is that the user should be able to change the year , the user selects which year he want to see its movies

Comment: If that is the case you might want to change your post instead of saying current year.

Comment: Posting the code for the getCurrentYearMovies function would be very helpful. According to their doc, the page # is optional, so omitting it might do what you want. They may limit the result set to avoid pounding their server though.

Comment: getCurrentYearMovies : just sending the request , i omit using page# in the request but it only returns the first page (mentioned in their doc) . it only returns one page , if you need more pages add page# parameter in the request , but i need to get all at once not page by page